# Validation in a custom directive that is used multiple times on the same page (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a custom directive that has contains related inputs and dropdowns.  I've also used an isolate scope to properly bind the outer scope to the inner scope to assist with two databinding, and this also allows me to use the same directive multiple times on the same page.  All works well up to this point.  My next question is how to handle validation within the directive.

I no longer can use something along the lines of

```
ng-show="formName.controlname.$invalid && !formname.controlname.$pristine"
```

for the following 2 reasons,

1. My directive should not have to worry about the external form.
2. Because i'm using the same directive twice on the same page, using the syntax formName.controlname would actually map to two different controls.

Some ideas on this would be helpful at this point.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, but I discovered that using ng-form meets my requirement.

So in my directive mark up I added:

```
   <div ng-form="[some name]">
     .......
   </div>
```

Doing this allowed me to continue to use the ng-* attributes.

Now I can do this in my directive:

```
ng-show="somename.controlname.$invalid && !somename.controlname.$pristine"
```

It is self contained so I don't have to worry about crossing any boundaries. I can add the control over and over again and validation stays intact per directive.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not make your directive depend on the form name. What you should do instead is to provide a parent form directive dependency so you can use its controller in your directive link function:

```
.directive('yourDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: '^form',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, formController) {
            // use formController.$errors object
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should do the validation in your directive.

Create a copy of the two-way bound scope members (assuming these are bound to the form inputs) to check pristine-ness and undo-ability.